# How can I consolidate the creation and excution of a bool into one statement?

Tags: c#, game-engine

Please forgive me, I'm totally self taught so there may be a glaringly obvious solution to this that I am missing.

Currently, when I want something to have a random chance of occurring, I do the following:

```
//Creates a 1 in 5 chance for text to be displayed
bool TxtDisplayChance = RandomChanceRetBool(5);

//Displays text if the bool won the lottery
if (TxtDisplayChance == true) {GameText.DisplayToUser();}
```

How can I cut the bool out of this, and just make some kind of function that only executes code in a block if the winning number is picked. For example, I want to create something to where I Can just type this

```
RunCodeIf(5)
{ Code goes here}
```

Below is the current code for the function I have:

```
 public static bool RandomChanceRetBool(byte ChanceHigherBound)
    {
        //If you just want a quick true/false based on a winning roll but don't have a bool to assign it to

        int WinningRoll = Rando.RollDice(ChanceHigherBound);
        int ActualRoll = Rando.RollDice(ChanceHigherBound);



        if (ActualRoll == WinningRoll)
        {
            return true;
        }
        else
        {
            return false;
        }


    }
```

Comment: `if (RandomChanceRetBool(5)) {GameText.DisplayToUser();}`

Comment: Nice that seems to work, I didn't think it would. Excellent. Is there anyway to eliminate the if from it?

Comment: you can remove last if & else block in RandomChanceRetBool with "return ActualRoll == WinningRoll;"

Comment: infact whole method with "return Rando.RollDice(ChanceHigherBound) == Rando.RollDice(ChanceHigherBound);"

Comment: Why would you want to eliminate the `if`? There's nothing wrong with it.

Comment: I wanted to see if I could turn `if (RandomChanceRetBool(5)) {GameText.DisplayToUser();}` into `(RandomChanceRetBool(5)) {GameText.DisplayToUser();}`

Answer (score 0):

Changed the name of RandomChanceRetBool to OneIn, and now call it directly without creating a separate bool:

```
if OneIn(5) {GameText.DisplayToUser();}
```